# Finding A-U, C-G and G-U pair proporstion in a sequence in R

Tags: r, string, indexing, structure

I have been wandering through this programmatic problem but I have not reached a clear answer yet...

I have two objects, say a and b. Object a is a string, representing an RNA sequence, like this:

```
> a
[1] "C" "A" "C" "C" "U" "U" "G" "U" "C" "C" "U" "C" "A" "C" "G" "G" "U" "C" "C" "A" "G" "U" "U" "U" "U" "C" "C" "C" "A" "G"
[31] "G" "A" "A" "U" "C" "C" "C" "U" "U" "A" "G" "A" "U" "G" "C" "U" "G" "A" "G" "A" "U" "G" "G" "G" "G" "A" "U" "U" "C" "C"
[61] "U" "G" "G" "A" "A" "A" "U" "A" "C" "U" "G" "U" "U" "C" "U" "U" "G" "A" "G" "G" "U" "C" "A" "U" "G" "G"
```

And object b is another string, representing a folding structure, where "(" symbols represents that a letter from a, is paired with another letter in the same sequence, represented as ")". The symbol "." means that this letter is not paired.

The object b looks like this:

```
> b
[1] "." "." "(" "(" "." "(" "(" "." "(" "(" "(" "(" "(" "." "(" "(" "." "." "(" "(" "(" "(" "." "(" "(" "." "(" "(" "(" "("
[31] "(" "(" "(" "(" "(" "(" "(" "(" "." "." "." "." "." "." "." "." "." "." "." "." "." ")" ")" ")" ")" ")" ")" ")" ")" ")"
[61] ")" ")" ")" "." ")" ")" "." ")" ")" ")" ")" "." "." ")" ")" ")" ")" ")" ")" ")" "." ")" ")" "." ")" ")"
```

If you count the number of characters in each objects a and b, they are the same, so that it means that first character in b corresponds to the first character in a, and so on. Say, in this case, a[1] which is "C", corresponds to b[1], which is ".", meaning that this letter in the sequence is not paired, but when we reach b[3], it is "(", the first paired letter in a, that corresponds to a[3] or "C". This first "("in b, paired letter "C", in a, joins to the last ")" symbol in b, which corresponds to b[86] and therefore corresponds to a[86], which is "G".

The first "(" in b forms a pair with the last ")" in b, and so on.

As you can see, my goal is to determine how many A-U, C-G and G-U pairs occur in the sequence.

I have the information there, but I cannot think of a programmatic aproach in R (where I am constructing my algorithm to extract other features from this two objects), that deals with this problem.

I have thought of extracting the index numbers of each "(" and each ")", and use it to find the corresponding letter in a, and then combining a[3] with a[86] and so on, to form another object.

The desired output would be something like constructing an object consisting in the combination of pairs, say c:

```
> c
[1] "CG" "CG" "UA" "GC" "CG" "CG" "UA" "CG" "AU" "GU" "GC"....
```

So that from this, I can count how many CG, GC and adding them them, how many AU, UA and adding them, and how many GU or UG and adding them, hence obtaining how many A-U, G-C and G-U are there in the sequence.

Any help?

Comment: You need to construct a [context-free grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar) for RNA folding and run it on your input. There might be an existing R implementation but I’m not aware of one. Asking on https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/ might increase your chances in this case.

Answer (score 0):

When all "(" come before the first ")", then you can simply extract the two sub-vectors, reverse the second and combine them:

```
data.frame(pair1 = a[b == "("], pair2 = rev(a[b == ")"]))
```

Alternatively you could use

```
mapply(paste0, a[b == "("], rev(a[b == ")"]))
```

If you are actually looking for a general solution with more than one loop, you can combine a `stack` with a `for` loop:

```
library(dequer)
s <- stack()
q <- queue()
for (i in seq_along(a)) {
    if(b[i] == "(")
        push(s, a[i])
    else if(b[i] == ")") 
        pushback(q, paste0(pop(s), a[i]))
}
unlist(as.list(q))
```

Comment: This approach gives wrong results since an RNA structure can have more than one loop. So, for instance, `((.))..(.).` is a valid structure. You really won’t get around using a CFG.

Comment: @KonradRudolph The OP seems to be looking for a special case solution since he said that the first "(" forms a pair with the last ")".  This fits the sample data. For the general case you can use a stack and loop over the input vectors.